# 'firebase_admin.db' has no attribute 'child'

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

While I was trying to practice on python and firebase I got this error.

```
 'firebase_admin.db' has no attribute 'child'
```

here is my imports

```
from firebase_admin import db
```

and the code that gives error.

```
dates = db.child("notes").get()
```

I have no idea why this error pops up. when I read firebase_admin documents it shows there is a `child()` method.
What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `db` is a [`firebase_admin.db` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db), which (as the error says) doesn't have a `child()` method. To get a reference from the top-level, you'll use the `reference` method:

```
dates = db.reference("notes").get()
```

To get references to lower-level nodes, you can use `child` on the result of `reference`, so for example:

```
db.reference("notes").child("nameofchildnode")
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting started with the Python Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#python).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @frank-van-puffelen.  Your logic here is great.